# Magento 2 oauth request token Error

Tags: magento2, oauth, token

I having issue to request token with oauth
https://www.host.com/magento2/oauth/token/request

[image]

**Error**:

> oauth_problem=oauth_consumer_key+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_signature+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_signature_method+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_nonce+is+a+required+field%2C+oauth_timestamp+is+a+required+field

Answer (score 0):

Magento Social (Integration) needs  PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) to be active.

I had the same error message and got fixed by swithing on PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 0):

isnt the address changed?

According to this:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

address would be
Get an admin token  POST /V1/integration/admin/token

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to get request token don't need to fill access token and secret key field,
fill like below picture,[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to send these details as part of Authorization header not Oauth